# Typescript error in Nextjs server actions, prisma, and nextauth

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I'm learning to program. For practice, I'm creating a simple app where users can login and save their notes. It's a nextjs app with vercel postgres, and prisma. I'm using nextauth for authentication.

I think I managed to add prisma and also nextauth. Now I try to make a simple request to the database that adds a note that belongs to a user.

The problem is that I'm getting a typescript error that says: **"Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'."**

It comes from the **email: session?.user?.email** row in the code below.

Has anyone experienced this kind of issue and how have you solved it?

```
import { options } from "../../api/auth/[...nextauth]/options";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import db from "../../api/db";

export default async function Page() {
  const session = await getServerSession(options);
  if (!session) return;

  async function addNote() {
    "use server";
    const res = await db.notes.create({
      data: {
        content: "Apple",
        category: "Fruit",
        owner: {
          connect: {
            email: session?.user?.email,
          },
        },
      },
    });
    return res;
  }

  const result = await addNote();
  console.log(result);
  return <></>;
}
```

I think I could somehow check that it is a string beforehand. Or, I could use type assertion, because I don't know how could it not be a string.

But I think I'm doing something wrong if I do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Three possible solutions:
1- You could check for the user and the email like:

```
if (session.user && session.user.email){
....
}
```

2- Or if you are sure there will be a user (like the route is protected..etc), you can use assertion like:

```
 email: (session?.user?.email as strin),
```

3- or you can use a fixed string value in case email is undefined or null like:

```
 email: session?.user?.email || "",
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code requires `email` to be of type `string`. You can convert that and make the required type include `null` and `undefined` because email might not always be available.

For now, a quick fix would be to covert `email: session?.user?.email` into `email: session?.user?.email as unknown as string`. This will force the type of email to be string so it is compatible with what is required.